# How to name Spring service component class corresponding to a model 'Service'?

Tags: java, spring, service, microservices, terminology

I am working on a model class `Service`. 
For performing operations around this model, a Spring service layer component(annotated with @Service) is created.

Normally, we would create service layer classes with 'Service' postfix in the classname.

By doing this, this class's name would be `ServicesService`. This is confusing since the word service apears twice in the classname.

1. I thought of using 'Module' instead of service. But a single service can have multiple modules. So, I have ruled this solution out.
2. Another solution was to prefix the className with the Application or the project name. But still the word Service will appear twice in the classname.

Is there a better alternative name to 
`ServicesService`?

---

Edit 1: Finally decided to use in the format `<ApplicationName>ServicesManagementService`. eg. `MyAppServicesManagementService`

Comment: Usually, Spring suffixes its class with `Default` or `Simple`. That said, there is no common universally agreed convention. Your naming convention is a more generally used convention. `ServicesService` seems to be good enough name as it tells us that `ServicesService` is service layer exposing business logic related to `Service` model.

Comment: The api I'm working on currently has a `ServicesService`... it's not beautiful, but it's still easy to understand